# How to map two different values based on same key from two different objects

Tags: javascript, object

I have two different objects

object1 = [{Id: 6, Type: "something", id_: 3}, {Id: 12, Type: "something", id_: 6}]

object2 = [{id:18, id_:6}, {id: 15, id_:3}]

the expected result should be

object = [{Id: 6, id:15}, {Id: 12, id: 18}]

I want to do this without using loop because the data is too big, is there some better way to do it using map/reduce?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is really weird that object 1 use Id and object use id. I'm not sure that is typo problem or not.

My solution is simple transform your array object into object with key and value. Then using the loadash/mergeWith to manipulate the data if the object got the same key.

```js
const object1 = [{Id: 6, Type: "something", id_: 3}, {Id: 12, Type: "something", id_: 6}]

const object2 = [{id:18, id_:6}, {id: 15, id_:3}]

const transformedObject1 =  object1.reduce((acc,item) => {acc[item.id_] = {Id: item.Id}; return acc; },{})
const transformedObject2 =  object2.reduce((acc,item) => {acc[item.id_] = {id: item.id}; return acc; },{})

function customizer(objValue, srcValue) {
   return {...objValue,...srcValue}
}

const output = _.values(_.mergeWith(transformedObject1, transformedObject2, customizer))
console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, it is not typo the object has those key. your answer is perfect.

Comment: It's nice when my answer can help you

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to generate an object with similar keys, such as {id:6, id: 15}, what about trying with [{key:3, ids: [6, 15]}] pattern.
old one

```
var obj1 = [{Id: 6, Type: "something", id_: 3}, {Id: 12, Type: "something", id_: 6}]
// object = [{Id: 6, id:15}, {Id: 12, id: 18}]
var obj2 = [{id:18, id_:6}, {id: 15, id_:3}]
var comb = obj1.concat(obj2)


var result  = comb.reduce((acc, i ) => { 
  const isExists =  acc.find(({key}) => key === i.id_)
    const {list } = typeof isExists !== "undefined" ? isExists : {}
    const dyno = typeof list !== "undefined" ? list : []
    console.log(isExists, ">>", i)
  
  return [...acc.filter(({key}) => key !== i.id_), {key: i.id_, list: dyno.concat(i.id)}]
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Updated one

```
var obj1 = [{Id: 6, Type: "something", id_: 3}, {Id: 12, Type: "something", id_: 6}]

var obj2 = [{id:18, id_:6}, {id: 15, id_:3}]
var comb = obj1.concat(obj2)


var result  = comb.reduce((acc, i ) => { 
  const isExists =  acc.find(({key}) => key === i.id_)
    const {list } = typeof isExists !== "undefined" ? isExists : {}
    const dyno = typeof list !== "undefined" ? list : {}
       console.log(i[Object.keys(i)[0]])
    const tmplist = {[Object.keys(i)[0]]: i[Object.keys(i)[0]], ...dyno}
 
  return [...acc.filter(({key}) => key !== i.id_), {key: i.id_, list: tmplist}]
}, [])

console.log(result)
console.log(result.map(({list}) => list ))
```

output
 `Array [Object { id: 18, Id: 12 }, Object { id: 15, Id: 6 }]`

Comment: hello, thank you for response, sorry for my question, the first is capital I and second one is small i, I have two different object in object1 there is id_ which could be same with other object key, if they are same I want to map first object 'Id' with second object 'id', in first object Id is with capital I and in second it is with small i.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it when posting my suggestion

Comment: thank you for your answer, this works perfect is the key in both object has same key "id" but in my case the first object has "Id" with capital I and in second it is "id" with small i